# Передача NULL в puts() и другие функции: как подавить "null argument where non-null required" warning на аналог if(NULL) puts(NULL);

Tags: c, препроцессор

Есть такой макрос:

```
#define __ex_msg (__ex_idx && __ex_idx < TCM_MAX) ? \
                 __ex_msgs[__ex_idx-1] : (const char *)0
```

Соответственно, в такой конструкции:

```
if(__ex_msg) puts(__ex_msg);
```

Получаем справедливую плюху:

```
null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
```

Единственное, что пока приходит в голову - разбить на 2 макроса, как-то так:

```
#define __ex_have_msg (__ex_idx && __ex_idx < TCM_MAX) ? \
                      __ex_msgs[__ex_idx-1] : (const char *)0
#define __ex_msg __ex_msgs[__ex_idx-1]
```

Но это мне почему-то не очень нравится. Что тут можно ещё придумать, кроме выноса `__ex_msg()` в функцию? Отключать warnings не предлагать :)

Comment: `if(NULL) unreachable;` гарантировано в С, поэтому сообщение не должно печататься даже там, где представление NULL не состоит из одних нулей (бит). То есть, даже если NULL ссылается на `0xdeadbeef` адрес, `if(NULL)` и `if(NULL != 0)` или наоборот `if(!NULL)` и `if(NULL == 0)` всё равно работают. [Is the abbreviated pointer comparison `if(p)` to test for non-null pointers valid? What if the internal representation for null pointers is nonzero?](http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html) (в сноске говорится, что в c89 `assert(NULL);` может сломаться (в c99, c++ поправили) но `if(NULL)` работает везде).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is NULL always false?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/459743/4279)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как это решает проблему?

Comment: 1- Это комментарий, а не ответ. 2- вы говорите: *"Отключать warnings не предлагать :)"* Я говорю: сообщение про `if(NULL) puts(NULL);` бесполезно: `puts(NULL);` никогда не выполнится (если у вас код внутрь `if(NULL)` ветки может прыгнуть, то у вас бóльшие проблемы, чем просто шумные диагностические сообщения). Можете bug report создать для инструмента, который это сообщение генерирует.

Comment: Один вариант как избежать шума я предложил. Но он мне почему-то не нравится, почему - не знаю :) Хотелось бы ещё варианты прикинуть.

Comment: вы написали: *"Получаем справедливую плюху:"* — мой комментарий говорит, что сообщение неоправданно в данном случае.

Comment: Насчёт оправданности или неоправданности - это к авторам gcc, у меня задача убрать это сообщение.

Comment: слова: *"справедливую плюху"* написали вы, а не авторы gcc. Я уже предложил вам bug report создать—у вас проблемы, вы и должны report составлять.

Comment: Ну, это баг в gcc. Если они не могут _доказать_, что передаётся `NULL`, пусть и не выдают warning.

Comment: Я не думаю что это ошибка gcc , так как один проход компилятора, вначале идет `if(NULL)` это корректно , а потом идет `puts(NULL)` здесь предупреждение.

Answer (score 1):

Использование `puts()` обязательно

```
if(__ex_msg){
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",__ex_msg)
```

или можно преобразовать `define`

```
#define __ex_msg  if( __ex_idx && __ex_idx < TCM_MAX) \
                    puts(__ex_msgs[__ex_idx-1]);
```